# Make a div a child of another div using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've created a div `adiv` how would I make this div a child of `bdiv` using Javascript?

Comment: Does bdiv already exist? Can you post a snippet of markup so we can see the structure of your html?

Comment: @InfernalBadger: Appending a child is not something jQuery is really needed for.

Comment: Not to be picky, but I think quite a few of your questions could be more easily answered by Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `adiv` is created in Javascript and `bdiv` is created declaratively on the page:

```
document.getElementById("bdiv").appendChild(adiv);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sample code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function appendDiv()
{
    var div1=document.getElementById('div1');//get the div element
    var div2=document.createElement("div");//create a new div
    div2.innerHTML="div2";

    div1.appendChild(div2);// append to div
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload=appendDiv()>
<div id="div1">
div1
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you've got your `bdiv` and `adiv` references to HTMLElements:

```
bdiv.appendChild(adiv);
```

adds `adiv` to `bdiv` as a last children.

Answer (score 0):

see a complete example :
http://jsfiddle.net/XFMUp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp) function as follows:

```
<div id="diva">a</div>
<div id="divb">b</div>
```

The use the following javaScript to move the div having removed it.

```
var diva = document.getElementById("diva");
var divb = document.getElementById("divb");

diva.appendChild(divb);
```

Check out [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/swaff/F2a7R/) on jsFiddle